# jQuery CSS 'display: none' issue sometimes on PageLoad

Tags: php, jquery, css, .post

I am loading some text from a database via $.post. Sometimes on page load the screen is just blank, when I inspect element the div it is set to `<div id="#panel" style="display:none">`, I don't know why this is happening, though before the `$.post` I am fading out the div and when the `$.post` gets an output, I bring back the div.

`$('#panel').html(output).show();`

I am using `$("#panel").fadeOut(100);` so I can make my loading.gif work.

Is there any way to check if #panel's style is set to display:none and if it is, then remove it.

Thanks.

EDIT: My function I call on checkbox change and page load

```
$("#loading").show();
$("#panel").fadeOut(100);
$('#options :input').prop('disabled', true);
$('#loading').html("<img src='loading.gif'>"); 
var langSelected = $('input[name=text]:checked').map(function() {return $(this).parent().text();}).get().join(",");

$.post('http://mywebsite.com/data.php', { value: languages.url.value, mycheckboxes: langSelected},
function(output) {
    $('#panel').html(output).show(); 
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#options :input').removeAttr('disabled');

});
```

Comment: Can you show us the `$.post` code as well?

Comment: You're setting it to `display:none` yourself when you are fading it out, and if the `$.post` encounters an error, the element will not be faded in, hence the page is blank ?

Comment: When I was inspecting the div on chrome, it was set to display:none, however there was content (text I wanted from database) in it.

Comment: Then your issue is with fading it in properly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($('#panel').is(':hidden')) {
     $('#panel').remove()
}
```

or:

```
$('#panel:hidden').remove()
```

However instead of removing the div you can use the `error` method:

```
$.post("example.php", function() {
      // success
}).error(function() { 
      $('#panel').show()
      // error
})
```

Comment: error(function() { 
      get(); // Calling my function again to do post.
})

Thanks a lot, so far no problems.